# How to create a dynamic admin panel with php forms and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

First off, if this question is duplicated, please let me know, as I am unsure as to how to search this particular question.

I am attempting to create an admin panel of sorts that allows the user (with admin permissions) access to delete, modify, or add a record into a MySQL database.

Currently, I have a php page with some basic html displaying the data from my database in a table. I then want to have an option next to each row to delete or modify the row with a sql statement (such as insert, delete, update etc).

**Right now, I am having an issue where the variables that are passed to the form-specified page (deleteRecord) is the same no matter which row I chose. How can I fix this?**

Here is my relevant code:

SQL connect with table:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM residence_areas";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'>";
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Year</th><th>Gender</th><th>CWID</th><th>Hall</th><th>Email</th><th>TimeStamp</th><th>Delete</th><th>Modify</th><th>Add</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["first_name"]."</td><td>".$row["last_name"]. "</td><td>".$row["year"]."</td><td>".$row["gender"]."</td><td>".
        $row["cwid"]."</td><td>".$row["hall"]."</td><td>".$row["email"]."</td><td>".$row["timestamp"]."</td><td>
        <form action='deleteRecord.php'id='deleteRcord' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='rowName' value=".$row["id"].">
        <input type='hidden' name='rowFirstname' value=".$row["first_name"].">
        <a onclick='myFunction()' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
        </form>
        </td><td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></td><td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></td></tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "</table>";
```

And here is the page the delete button will go to (and in the future, send the sql statement that will actually delete the requested row):

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
$id=$_POST['rowName'];
$firstName= $_POST['rowFirstname'];
echo "You are deleting $firstName. Their user id was: ".$id;
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: you are trying to tell that you are not getting value for `$id`? while trying to delete

Comment: When I click on the 'submit' button for either John Doe or Jane Doe's row, it returns the same id when it should be returning different IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Type Button**

Change Line

```
<a onclick='myFunction()' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
```

To

```
<input type='submit' value='del'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>
```

**2) Anchor Tag**

Change Line

```
<a onclick='myFunction()' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
```

To

```
<a href='#' onclick='formSubmit();'>Example to post<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
```

Include Jquery and define Function

```
function formSubmit()
{
     document.getElementById("deleteRcord").submit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It now shows the correct matching information. As a side question, would it be possible to make this into a link rather than a button?

Comment: Yes, make it
<a href="postForm">Del here</a>
function postForm(){
// your logic to post form data 
}
If my answer help you then please vote for it

Comment: <a href="javascript:$('#deleteRcord').submit()">Example to post</a>